# How to start android emulator from titanium studio

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have recently started titanium studio .. i could not figure out how to open android emulator on titanium studio , even emulator from android studio is not working with titanium studio .

Comment: Have you set the path of android sdk properly? if yes go to run and Run your app, by selecting any of the options.

Comment: i have figured it out .. beside the run button i have a dropdown which allows me to select android devices .. i have created an emulator from android studio and set the device to this emulator in titanium studio .. thank you for the reply anyway .

Comment: On a related note, the emulator provided by the android sdk is awful. I would highly recommend using Genymotion -- http://www.genymotion.com/ as a replacement.